# Facebook share completion listener

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have something i am really stuck at. The thing is that i am trying to catch the completion when some one is done with sharing something on facebook

i am using the following function to execute and catch the completion. But i am not getting the result.

```
public void FaceBookSharing() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Running facebook share");

        Log.d(TAG, "Share on facebook 1: "+sport);
        Log.d(TAG, "Share on facebook 2: "+speed);
        Log.d(TAG, "Share on facebook 3: "+distance);
        Log.d(TAG, "Share on facebook 4: "+date);



        Log.d(TAG, "Shared image url: "+sharedImage);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        final ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel");
            }
        });

        ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Mijn workout "+sport+" | " +speed+" | "+ distance+" | "+ date+" is gesponsord door "+Company)
                .setContentDescription(shareDesc)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(mUrl))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(sharedImage))
                .build();

        ShareDialog.show(advertise.this,shareLinkContent);

    }
```

I have searched everywhere and i am unable to find a suiting solution to my problem also i am not really good with listeners.

Thank you.

Comment: Listeners / Callbacks are quite simple. What exactly isn't working with those `onSuccess`, `onError`, or `onCancel` methods?

Comment: Why do you need to know if someone shared something?

Comment: well onSuccess is not being executed at all. I need this so i can record if something has been shared and users get points for sharing something.

Comment: maybe i need to init the sharedialog in onCreate and not in the method?

Comment: __You are not allowed to reward users for sharing in any way.__ Please go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) before you proceed.

Comment: it doesn't say that anywhere on their page and i know several apps who do it. So i think you can do that. Also it is not forced. But lets get back to the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved as i forgot to init the call back in oncreate.